# Large 2D Array Storage in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I'm creating a matrix in Java, which:

- Can be up to 10,000 x 10,000 elements in the worst case
- May change size from time to time (assume on the order of days)
- Stores an integer in the range 0-5 inclusive (presumably a `byte`)
- Has elements accessed by referring to a pair of `Long` IDs (system-determined)
- Is symmetrical (so can be done in half the space, if needed, although it makes things like summing the rows harder (or impossible if the array is unordered))
- Doesn't necessarily need to be ordered (unless halved into a triangle, as explained above)
- Needs to be persistent after the app closes (currently it's being written to file)

My current implementation is using a `HashMap<Pair<Long,Long>,Integer>`, which works fine on my small test matrix (10x10), but according to [this article](http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/), is probably going to hit unmanageable memory usage when expanded to 10,000 x 10,000 elements.

I'm new to Java and Android and was wondering: what is the best practice for this sort of thing?

I'm thinking of switching back to a bog standard 2D array `byte[][]` with a `HashMap` lookup table for my `Long` IDs. Will I take a noticable performance hit on matrix access? Also, I take it there's no way of modifying the array size without either:

1. Pre-allocating for the assumed worst-case (which may not even be the worst case, and would take an unnecessary amount of memory)
2. Copying the array into a new array if a size change is required (momentarily doubling my memory usage)

Comment: Could you store it in the file and avoid loading the whole thing into memory at once?

Comment: @immibis potentially. As I say, I'm quite new to Android, and not very familiar with its file reading mechanisms (which is why I mentioned the fact I need to save it). Presumably the file is loaded into some sort of limited buffer? If I read it from file, will this be a lot slower than reading from RAM?

Comment: Is the `Pair<Long, Long>` effectively the X/Y coordinate in the matrix?  If so, don't keep a map to individual cells, you only need maps of arbitrary Long to a 0-based row index (max 10,000 entries) and again the same for the columns.  That's `2n` instead of `n^2` space.  Once you have the indexes, a full 10k X 10k `byte[][]` would cost roughly 100 MB.  If you store only the upper triangle or are willing to pack bits into `int`s you can get it smaller.  How many instances do you expect to be live at any one time?

Comment: Would keeping values in a SQLite DB be an option? In Android it is not a big deal to handle and it gives you sql functions (count, sum, group ... ) for free.

Comment: @WilliamPrice Yes, the `Pair<Long,Long>` is the x,y coordinate in the matrix. I know that this isn't necessary to store, hence my own suggestion of storing them in a `HashMap`. I only expect to have a single instance of this matrix, unless I'm changing its size, in which case I'd expect to temperorarily have two.

Comment: @Fildor an SQLite DB could be an option, but I'm not familiar with its capabilities (hence asking for best practice so I can do some more reading). 
Presumably if I went the SQLite route, I'd have to store a pair of columns: the `Long` ID I use to reference a row/column, and then a Serialized array of `byte`s? Is there a large overhead associated with calling a row, unserializing and then searching for a value (compared with storing a local array)?

Comment: You have 3 Columns: LongID_X, LongID_Y, Value. So you can select all Values of a column, all values of a row, all values of all columns of a specified row, all values of all rows of a specified column ... row - sum, column sum ... overhead should be reasonably low, considered that you'd run into memory problems using an actual 2D-Array.

Comment: @Fildor makes a good recommendation if the goal is to minimize the RAM requirements on the device.  In that case your interface to the "matrix" would be SQL.  That's not a bad option if you only need to do basic aggregations like summing rows/columns.  However, if you plan to do matrix-type operations (e.g. inverse) or need random access to individual cells then that sort of interface to the data might be a hindrance and you pay the cost of keeping the data in RAM.  TNSTAAFL.

Comment: Yes, I'm now trying to implement an SQL database as @Fildor suggested. It's a particularly good method for a persistent matrix. I've tried it on a small matrix, but not yet a large one. I get the feeling that it's an expensive method for initialising the matrix, but hopefully that's a one-off that the user will just have to put up with.

Comment: Is it always the same start values? Then you could prepare one db and copy it.

Comment: @Fildor - actually thought of a much simpler idea. The entire matrix is initialised with a single (in my case non-zero) value. Given that I have a list of valid rows and columns, I'm implementing a helper function that will simply return this default value if no SQL entry is found. Summing is still possible by returning the number of entries found and multiplying my default value by the number of "missing" entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd answer this for posterity. I've gone with Fildor's suggestion of using an SQL database with two look-up columns to represent the row and column indices of my "matrix". The value is stored in a third column.

The main benefit of this approach is that the entire matrix doesn't need to be loaded into RAM in order to read or update elements, with the added benefit of access to summing functions (and any other features inherently in SQL databases). It's a particularly easy method on Android, because of the built-in SQL functionality.

One performance drawback is that the initialisation of the matrix is extraordinarily slow. However, the approach I've taken is to assume that if an entry isn't found in the database, it takes a default value. This eliminates the need to populate the entire matrix (and is especially useful for sparse matrices), but has the downside of not throwing an error if trying to access an invalid index. It is recommended that this approach is coupled with a pair of lists that list the valid rows and columns, and these lists are referenced before attempting to access the database. If you're trying to sum rows using the built-in SQL features, this will also not work correctly if your default is non-zero, although this can be remedied by returning the number of entries found in the row/column being summed, and multiplying the "missing" elements by the default value.